# Date object: set static time when created (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, date, static, timezone

I want to create a date object, and have the time saved as I put it there.

An example:

`var date = new Date(2011, 06, 13, 7, 15, 0, 0);`

Right now, when I create a date object, it edits the time to my time zone, and I don't want that.
So for example, if I create a time '7:15' it will edit it to '5:15' because i'm in GMT + 2.

I just want it to be created as 7:15, and don't look at the timezone.

How can this be done? I hope my problem is clear enough.

Thanks!

Tjellekes

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: This should not happen. When you call `new Date(2011, 6, 13, 7, 15, 0, 0)` you should get a localized date. I for example get this: `Wed Jul 13 2011 07:15:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`. Are you sure you don't have a third party library in action that overwrites the default behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the resulting date with [timezone offset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) like this:

```
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + date.getTimezoneOffset());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Date(+new Date(2011, 06, 13, 7, 15, 0, 0) + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```